# how to know what is the running context

Tags: linux, multithreading, swap, ucontext

I am writing a small program in C that creates an array of three structures of type ucontext_t. The program uses swapcontext command to switch between these 3 contexes.

My question is: do I have any ability to know the identity of the context that runs at the moment? I would expect to find a function/command that gives the identifier of the context that is running at the current time. Do you know such a function/command?
Maybe there is any way to figure it out using the debugger?

thanks a lot!